# How can I return a list or enumerable of rows where column value has changed with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable:

```
Position Price
1        1.2
1        1.3
2        1.25
1        1.4
1        1.3
2        1.35
```

I want to return all rows where Position has changed:

```
Position Price
2        1.25
1        1.4
2        1.35
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with Linq?

I tried:

```
var trades = Enumerable.Range(1, Data.Rows.Count - 1)
              .Where(i => !Data.Rows[i].Field<string>("Position").Equals(Data.Rows[i - 1].Field<string>("Position")));
```

but this returns a list of indices, not the rows.

Comment: @Backs See edit of question please

Comment: why you are selecting 2 twice but 1 only once?

Comment: @Rahul Because position changes from 1 to 2 then to 1 and back to 2... So change occurs three times... 2-1-2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
var positionChanges = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Skip(1)
    .Where((row, index) => table.Rows[index - 1].Field<string>(0) != row.Field<string>(0));
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for